# Scipy hypergeometric function returning NaNs

Tags: python, scipy

I need to use the hypergeometric (Kummers) function U(a,b,z) as decribed here (https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E6) for a model I am writing. I have noticed that in some cases the scipy function `scipy.special.hyperu` returns NaNs.

For example, this is a value that may appear in my model,

```
import scipy.special as sc

a = 5 / 8 - 1 / (2 * 0.361033 ** 3)
b = 5/4
x =  2 * 0.361033 ** 3 / (0.213429572 ** 4)

res = sc.hyperu(a,b,x)
print(res)
```

This returns NaN on my machine, even though I am pretty sure that it is a well defined value . Mathematica for example gives `1.74126e15`, as does the mpmath implementation in python. Running this script with error reporting turned on returns:

> scipy.special.sf_error.SpecialFunctionError: scipy.special/hypU: no result obtained

Anyone know what I might try to prevent this from happening. I would rather not throw away the NaNs if it can be prevented, since individual data points are pretty time expensive already. Thanks!

EDIT: Solved by updating Scipy, I was using version 1.4.1

Comment: Which version of SciPy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.  With version 1.5.2, I get `1741257268934676.2`.

Comment: I tested with Python 3.8.6 32-bit + scipy 1.5.3 and Python 3.8.6. 64-bit + scipy 1.5.2, and both give `1741257268934676.2`. Perhaps you are using some older scipy version?

Comment: Wow can't believe I didnt think of that, I was using scipy 1.4.1. Currently updating, thanks  a lot!